# How to set default value for a pair of buttons based on API response? VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend

I have a pair of buttons that has to be toggled based on the response I get from API.The button has to set only once when the page loads.

[image]

The code I am using for this

```
<div class="small-7 column btn-switch">
          <span class="switch-statement">"Is it mandatory"</span>
          <button
            :class="!isMandatory ? 'button--secondary' : 'button--tertiary'"
            class="button button-border"
            @click="setMandatory(false)"
          >
           "No"
          </button>
          <button
            :class="isMandatory ? 'button--secondary' : 'button--tertiary'"
            class="button"
            role=`your text`"button"
            @click="setisMandatory(true)"
          >
            "Yes"
          </button>
        </div>
```

I tried using v-if for the buttons and as i had expected it didnt work.Is there any alternate way of doing this?

Comment: I did not see any challenge in this requirement. Can you please paste some code where you are setting `isMandatory` value on page load. It will help me in better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that `isMandatory`'s value is changing depending on the response from the API call you are making. When the page is first loaded, it will be whatever default value you gave it, and when the API returns a response later, the page isn't being refreshed.

I would need more information on how your code is structured, but my current guess is that you need to turn your `isMandatory` into a `ref`.

For example, if your code looks something like this:

```html
<script setup>
  isMandatory = false;

  // -> some API call handling
  isMandatory = apiResponse
</script>
<template>
  ...
</template>
```

Turn it into something like:

```html
<script setup>
  isMandatory = ref(false);

  // -> some API call handling
  isMandatory.value = apiResponse
</script>
<template>
  ...
</template>
```

Then `template` will reactively change whenever the value of `isMandatory` changes.

Comment: The value is set only once when the page is loaded for the first time. How can i add it to the button to switch based on this value?

Comment: @ajithsadanandan The value is probably not set **when** the page is loaded. You're probably making the API call **at page load**, and the value is set after that (when it responds). That's why you need reactivity -- set your `isMandatory` as a `ref`. Probably the simplest solution I can come up with.